# Concurrent future polling of series of blocking calls

Tags: python, python-asyncio, concurrent.futures

I'm trying to generate a polling mechanism for a long running task in Python. To do this, I'm using a concurrent Future and poll with `.done()`. The task exists of many iterations that are themselves blocking, which I wrapped in an async function. I don't have access to the code of the blocking functions as I'm calling third-party software. This is a minimal example of my current approach:

```
import asyncio
import time

async def blocking_iteration():
    time.sleep(1)

async def long_running():
    for i in range(5):
        print(f"sleeping {i}")
        await blocking_iteration()

async def poll_run():
    future = asyncio.ensure_future(long_running())
    while not future.done():
        print("before polling")
        await asyncio.sleep(0.05)
        print("polling")
    future.result()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(poll_run())
    loop.close()
```

The result of this is:

```
before polling
sleeping 0
sleeping 1
sleeping 2
sleeping 3
sleeping 4
polling
```

From my current understanding of the asyncio mechanism in Python, I had expected the loop to unblock after the first sleep, return control to the loop that would go back to the poll_run `await` statement and would only run the second iteration of the long_running function after the subsequent poll.
So desired output is something like this:

```
before polling
sleeping 0
polling
before polling
sleeping 1
polling
before polling
sleeping 2
polling
before polling
sleeping 3
polling
before polling
sleeping 4
polling
```

Can this be achieved with the current approach somehow, or is it possible in a different way?

**EDIT**

Thanks to @drjackild was able to solve it by changing

```
async def blocking_iteration():
    time.sleep(1)
```

into

```
def blocking():
    time.sleep(1)

async def blocking_iteration():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    await loop.run_in_executor(None, blocking)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`time` is synchronous library and block whole main thread when executing. If you have such blocking calls in your program you can avoid blocking with thread or process pool executors (you can read about it [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#executing-code-in-thread-or-process-pools)). Or, change your `blocking_iteration` to use `asyncio.sleep` instead of `time.sleep`

UPD. Just to make it clear, here is non-blocking version, which use `loop.run_in_executor` with default executor. Please, pay attention, that `blocking_iteration` now without `async`

```py
import asyncio
import concurrent.futures
import time

def blocking_iteration():
    time.sleep(1)

async def long_running():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    for i in range(5):
        print(f"sleeping {i}")
        await loop.run_in_executor(None, blocking_iteration)

async def poll_run():
    task = asyncio.create_task(long_running())
    while not task.done():
        print("before polling")
        await asyncio.sleep(0.05)
        print("polling")
    print(task.result())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(poll_run())
    loop.close()
```